My Iframe Won't Load Correctly, And Is Not The Right Size
I am trying to make the icons work so that when I click on them, they open an iframe that contains the page that I want to go to so that the actual URL never changes, but the user can still access the subpages of the website. I set the "onclick=beep()" to the page I wanted it to appear as, but I instead just sends me to the website's main page. I will include screenshots to show what I mean. The iframe also only takes up the very top of the page, instead of taking up the whole page.
Website Before

Website After

What did I do wrong?


function beep(x) {
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe")
    var html = "<body>Foo</body>"
    document.getElementById('all').hidden = true
    iframe.src = x + encodeURI(html)
    document.body.appendChild(iframe)
  }  
body {
    background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom, #4D511F 0, #03260c 100%);}

h1{
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 5vw;
    color: #D0BF94;
}

.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    max-width: 100% !important;
    column-gap: 5vw;
    row-gap: 5vw;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

.game {
    width:10%;
    height:10%;
}

img {
    width:17vw;
}

iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
}
<div id="all">
      <h1>Website</h1>
      
      <div class="grid">
        <div class="game"><img src="images/goedash.png" alt="Geometry Dash" onclick="beep('example.github.io/pages/geodash/index.html')"></div>
        <div class="game"><a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></div>
        <div class="game"><a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a></div>
      </div>




I have made some adjustments to your code below. The iframe's src is now being assigned correctly and the iframe is filling the entire page. Mainly your issue was adding encodeURI(html) in the iframe's src.
I also added a back button to leave the iframe if the user would like. You can remove that part if you want.


function beep(url) {
  document.getElementById('all').hidden = true;

  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.src = url;
  iframe.style.position = "absolute";
  iframe.style.top = "0";
  iframe.style.left = "0";
  iframe.style.width = "100%";
  iframe.style.height = "100%";
  iframe.style.border = "none";
  iframe.style.zIndex = "1000";

  var closeButton = document.createElement("button");
  closeButton.textContent = "Back";
  closeButton.style.position = "absolute";
  closeButton.style.top = "10px";
  closeButton.style.right = "10px";
  closeButton.style.zIndex = "1001";
  closeButton.style.padding = "10px";
  closeButton.style.background = "red";
  closeButton.style.color = "white";
  closeButton.style.border = "none";
  closeButton.style.cursor = "pointer";

  closeButton.onclick = function () {
    document.body.removeChild(iframe);
    document.body.removeChild(closeButton);
    document.getElementById('all').hidden = false;
  };

  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
  document.body.appendChild(closeButton);
}
body {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at bottom, #4D511F 0, #03260c 100%);
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

iframe {
  display: block;
}
<div id="all">
  <h1>Website</h1>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="game">
      <img src="images/goedash.png" alt="Geometry Dash" onclick="beep('https://example.github.io/pages/geodash/index.html')">
    </div>
    <div class="game">
      <a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div class="game">
      <a href=""><img src="" alt=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



